# How to seek to a specific line in a file?

Tags: python, file, seek

I have a text file as follows:

```
1
/run/media/dsankhla/Entertainment/English songs/Apologise (Feat. One Republic).mp3
3
/run/media/dsankhla/Entertainment/English songs/Bad Meets Evil.mp3
5
/run/media/dsankhla/Entertainment/English songs/Love Me Like You DO.mp3
```

I want to search for a specifc line in the file let's say the line is
 `song_path = "/run/media/dsankhla/Entertainment/English songs/Bad Meets Evil.mp3"`
and then I want to seek `len(song_path)+2` BEHIND so that I can point to `3` in the file. How can I do this?
This is my code so far:

```
txt = open(".songslist.txt", "r+")
if song_path in txt.read():
    byte = len(song_path)
    txt.seek(-(byte), 1)
    freq = int(txt.readline())
    print freq     # 3
    freq = freq + 1
    txt.seek(-2,1)
    txt.write(str(freq))
    txt.close()
```

Comment: If your file is not too large and you can read it completly in memory you can use `readlines()` and simply look in the line n+1.

Comment: @syntonym the answer with the code will be helpful

Comment: @syntonym Even I need to change that line in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your file isn't too large (too large to fit in memory, pretty slow to read/write) you can circumvent any "low level" actions like seek and just read your file completely, change what you want to change, and write everything back.

```
# read everything in
with open(".songslist.txt", "r") as f:
    txt = f.readlines()

# modify
path_i = None
for i, line in enumerate(txt):
    if song_path in line:
        path_i = i
        break

if path_i is not None:
    txt[path_i] += 1 # or what ever you want to do

# write back
with open(".songslist.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(txt)
```

With `seek` you need to be careful when you don't write "byte perfekt", i.e:

```
f = open("test", "r+")
f.write("hello world!\n12345")
f.seek(6) # jump to the beginning of "world"
f.write("1234567") # try to overwrite "world!" with "1234567" 
# (note that the second is 1 larger then "world!")
f.seek(0)
f.read() # output is now "hello 123456712345" note the missing newline
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use seek, like in this example:

```
fp = open('myfile')
last_pos = fp.tell()
line = fp.readline()
while line != '':
  if line == 'SPECIAL':
    fp.seek(last_pos)
    change_line()#whatever you must to change
    break
  last_pos = fp.tell()
  line = fp.readline()
```

You must use `fp.tell` to assign the position value to a variable. Then with `fp.seek` you can go backward.